# extract texts from from pandas according to appearance location

Tags: python, pandas, text, location

I have words of a long text spread among a few pages. words, their page number and their font are all stored on a pandas dataframe. I need to find out where is the first time the word 'then' appears -and identify the page number (2 in the example) .Then, I need to extract on the same page no where 'then' first appeared (2 in this example), only the next three texts that appear after 'then' with the value 1 in 'font' column. in this example:['felt', 'painful', 'the']

words table:

| page no | text | font |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | they | 0 |
| 1 | ate | 0 |
| 1 | apples | 0 |
| 2 | and | 0 |
| 2 | then | 1 |
| 2 | their | 0 |
| 2 | stomach | 0 |
| 2 | felt | 1 |
| 2 | slightly | 0 |
| 2 | painful | 1 |
| 2 | given | 0 |
| 2 | the | 1 |
| 3 | fruit | 0 |

desired output: ['felt', 'painful', 'the']

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on OP's comment:

To find the first 'then':

```
df[df['text']=='then']
```

To find the page no of the first 'then':

```
pg_no = df.loc[df['text'] == 'then', 'page no'].values[0]
```

To find subsequent text with font val = 1 and the same page no:

```
print(df['text'].loc[(df['font']==1)&(df['page no'] == pg_no)&(df['text'] != 'then')].iloc[:3].tolist())
```

Output:

```
['felt', 'painful', 'the']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you need to combine the two, no? e.g., if there is a font with value 1 *before* the first "then", your second code would choose that as well.

Comment: I agree, but what if the page number is different for the second 'then'? There are a lot of conditions excluded by the OP. So at this point, its all based on our assumptions.

Comment: thanks, mine doesn't handle that, will delete

Comment: thanks @ShivikaP  . the first code: df[df['text']=='then'] just retrieves an empty dataframe, the second code retrieves a list (df['text'].loc[df['font']==1].tolist() . the output list now : ['then', 'felt', 'painful', the'], which is also good - now I need to extract the next three values after 'then'. My original list is much longer than that so I'm looking for a solution with no dependency on location but rather the next three items appearing after 'then' on the FONT=1 created list you've suggested. Many thanks!!

Comment: I've updated the code -- get the page no of the first then, use the page number and the font val = 1 to get subsequent words. If you want only 3, just limit it to 3. If you want two, change iloc[:3]. This would mean get only 2 values and then convert the result to a list.

Comment: thanks @ShivikaP , I'm receiving a"single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" error for the page_no code

Comment: Check it now? I've changed .iloc to .values[].